# Повторное выполнение программы. Как реализовать?

Tags: c#

Написал простой генератор паролей, который генерирует пароль заданной из консоли длинны.
Но как сделать так, чтобы после генерации программа предложила сгенерировать новый или совсем выйти из программы?

Вот код программы:

```
using System;

namespace PasswordGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string Pass = "";
            string rnd_psw = "1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLMNBVCXZ";
            int pass_lenght;

            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t###Типа дофига крутой генератор паролей!!###");

            Console.Write("Введите длинну пароля:");
            pass_lenght = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < pass_lenght; i ++)
            {
                Pass = Pass + rnd_psw[rnd.Next(0, rnd_psw.Length)];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ваш пароль:{0}", Pass);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Я понял одно, что нужен цикл, который при условии продолжения повторял бы генерацию или выходил закрыв программу. Но куда его "прикрутить".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t###Типа дофига крутой генератор паролей!!###");
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите длинну пароля:");
            pass_lenght = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < pass_lenght; i++)
            {
                Pass = Pass + rnd_psw[rnd.Next(0, rnd_psw.Length)];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ваш пароль:{0}", Pass);
            Console.WriteLine("Повторить? y/n");
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Y)
                break;
        }
```

Как то так, единственное в данном случае программа закроется если ввести что нибудь кроме Y, но это меняется в условии.

Comment: Спасибо. Это то что нужно.

Comment: @Petr и на будущее: слово **длина** пишется с одной **н**, а в **length** сначала идёт **t**, а потом **h**.

Comment: @Regent спешил просто:) Но в следующий раз учту.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace PasswordGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string Pass = "";
            string rnd_psw = "1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLMNBVCXZ";
            int pass_lenght;
            char restart;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t###Типа дофига крутой генератор паролей!!###");
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Введите длинну пароля:");
                pass_lenght = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Random rnd = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < pass_lenght; i++)
                {
                    Pass = Pass + rnd_psw[rnd.Next(0, rnd_psw.Length)];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Ваш пароль:{0}", Pass);
                Console.WriteLine("Повторить? y/n");
                restart = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                
                
            }
            while (restart == 'y') ;
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]